# OOM error when running custom Tensorflow training loop for MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote a custom Tensorflow training loop to train a MNIST classifier.
I experienced an error:

`OOM when allocating tensor for MNIST`

[The snap shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5JOf.png)

Here is my code: https://github.com/soon22/learningTensorflowCustomTrainingLoop/blob/master/mnist_custom_training_loop.ipynb

Using `tensorflow.keras` 's `model.compile` and `model.fit` ,the training was successful with more than 90% accuracy. It didn't have this problem.
What did I do wrong.

Comment: Assuming after training you're trying to run an eval or predict loop.  You are putting all 60,000 images in at once for this stage.  This will make it choke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to make the model do a prediction for all 60000 data points in the MNIST dataset at the same time, and compute gradients for the resulting loss. That is way too much for your graphics card to handle.

Try training on batches of say a hundred data points. The reason model.fit doesn't give an OOM is that that model.fit defaults to batches of size 32 if you don't specify another value for batch_size (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

Comment: U are correct. I ran with model.fit batch_size set to 60'000, OOM again. Thanks